# Practicing on matrix - Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am practicing on matrix at the moment but I am not really sure on the most efficient way to resolve some of the problems I encounter.

My first "problem" is to optimize a function. What I try to do is to iterate trough the 'a matrix which is a 'a array array.
For each line identified by an integer between 0 and 4 (the matrix has a size of (5,10)), I count how many "one" there is.

I had to split it in three different functions but I was wondering if there is any more optimized way to solve this problem ?

```
let count m i =
    let ret=Array.fold_left (fun x y -> if y=1 then x+1 else x) 0 (m.(i)) in 
    ret;;

let rec clear l =
    match l with 
        |[]->[]
        |(a,b)::[]->if b=0 then [] else (a,b)::[]
        |(a,b)::c->if b=0 then clear c else (a,b)::clear c;;

let all_moves s =
    match s with 
        |(a,_)->clear[(0,count a 0);(1,count a 1);(2,count a 2);(3,count a 3);(4,count a 4)];;
```

Second of all, my main problem is to iterate through the entire matrix at once.
I'm trying to count all the 1 in the matrix except for the line identified by param "i".
I tried several things but I'm really stuck at the moment.

```
let countall m i =
    let ret=Array.fold_left (fun x y -> if pos != i then x + y else ()) 
    (Array.fold_left (fun x y -> if y=1 then x+1 else x) 0 (m.(i))) 
    0 m in 
    ret;;
```

I would like to thank you in advance for your help and I thought I might give a matrix for you to test my functions:

```
let c = [|[|1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0|]; [|1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0|];
[|1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0|]; [|1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0|];
[|1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1|]|]
```

Sincerely yours, 
Rama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pointers:

1. Expressions of the form `let ret = expr in ret` can be simplified to `expr`. And the reverse application operator `|>` can often be used to elide trivial `let` expressions.
2. If a function starts with a match expression that has just a single clause, that clause can often be rolled into the function signature. E.g. `let all_moves s = match s with (a, _) -> ...` becomes `let all_moves (a, _) = ...'.
3. The `Array` and `List` modules have more than just fold functions (and alternative standard libraries, such as Core, Batteries, or ExtLib add more functionality to them) that can be used to simplify a lot of Array/List processing.

Example:

```
let count_ones row =
  Array.fold_left (fun c x -> if x=1 then c+1 else c) 0 row

let all_moves (mat, _) =
  Array.mapi (fun i row -> (i, count_ones row)) mat
  |> Array.to_list |> List.filter (fun (_, c) -> c != 0)
```

I'm not 100% sure what the intended semantics of `countall` are, but if I'm understanding it correctly, the following should work (it follows the basic structure of your attempted solution, but relies on `mapi` instead of `fold_left`, which is a better fit):

```
let countall mat k =
  Array.mapi (fun i row -> if i = k then 0 else count_ones row) mat
  |> Array.fold_left (+) 0
```

This function can be implemented in different ways, too, e.g.:

```
let countall mat k =
  Array.(append (sub mat 0 k) (sub mat (k+1) (length mat - k - 1)))
  |> Array.map count_ones |> Array.fold_left (+) 0
```

In this variant, I'm using a local open `Array.(expr)` so that I don't have to prefix every single array operation with `Array.`. Also, in both versions `(+)` is a way to write the plus operator as a function with two arguments, and is roughly equivalent to writing `(fun x y -> x + y)` in its place.

Comment: In fact mapi, is very very useful while working on matrix as we can apply a first function on the index and then on the line. 
It actually helped me a lot throughout the rest of my work. 

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that could help you

```
let countall m i =
  snd (
    Array.fold_left (fun (lg,c) v ->
      let c=
        if lg = i then c
        else
          Array.fold_left (fun c xy -> if xy=1 then c+1 else c) c v
      in
      (lg+1,c) 
    ) (0,0) m 
  )
;;
```

> Test

```
# countall c 0;;
- : int = 28
```

Comment: @RamaDesplats If you need explanations about countall, you have just to ask me (the picture of your profile is very nice).

Comment: If I'm understanding it right, I kinda have the general idea of how it works.
It takes the second element of the matrix which is the second array.
Then it iterates on it if it's not equal to i. 

Is it the (lg+1,c) that iterates through the first element of the matrix ?

Comment: @Rama Desplats, yes it's, (tu as tout compris).